# Query string values with their open and close quotation marks using Caigen CSV reader

Tags: java, csv

Good day,

I have a java program which uses Caigen CSV JDBC driver to query a CSV file and return its contents. Unfortunately the string values are returned without their open and close quotation marks. Is there a way for Caigen to query a specific CSV column and return its contents **with or without** the quotation marks included.

Example

TABLE.CSV

```
ROW 1.   "APPLE",$1.40
ROW 2.   ORANGE,$1.30
ROW 3.   "LEMON",$1.50

SQL: Select COLUMN1 from TABLE1

Expected results:
ROW 1.   "APPLE"     
ROW 2.    ORANGE    
ROW 3.   "LEMON"
```

Edit:
     The purpose of getting the quotation marks is to see if the external program (which I have no control) generated the CSV correctly. Missing quotation marks means that the CSV is incorrect.

Comment: Why do you need the returned data to contain the quotes?  Can you not just add them when you print them? Also, you didn't include your code, which makes the question off-topic.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clear that the double quotation marks are used to check if the CSV file was generated correctly. I'll correct my question

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "generated correctly". The usual definition of CSV does NOT require that non-ambiguous strings be quoted.  Missing quotes in an unambiguous situation is not an error, and if only one quote was missing then the file wouldn't be parseable as CSV and you'd probably get an exception from the library.  This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: You are correct @JimGarrison. In my case however there is a standard set within our organization that demands that the string values to be enclosed within quotation marks. The trouble is not everyone in the organization is following this rule when generating their CSV. My program is supposed to enforce the rules set and see if the CSV files follow them.

Comment: Then you must parse the CSV yourself. A standard parser will remove the quotes. (wailing and gnashing of teeth at the thought of someone writing yet-another-csv-parser-with-weird-non-standard-requirements).  I still think this is an XY Problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes in a CSV file are part of the structure of the file and are not part of the field itself. So CAIGEN is correct in removing them, and normally you should not worry for that.

If you need them, that means that you do not them to be processed as the CSV quoting character. IMHO, that means that you should configure CAIGEN to use another character as quote. **You** should choose another character that will not appear in your file. Assuming that the single quote (`'`) is an acceptable choice, just declare it in you connection string:

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:csv:[DatabasePath]?_CSV_Quoter='")
```

Comment: Question.... what if I already have something declared in my connection string like <"jdbc:csv:[DatabasePath]?_CSV_Header=true> How do I add the <?_CSV_Quoter='"> line?

Comment: @ides: it is explicit in [CAIGEN documentation](http://www.caigen.com/csv/doc.html#url). Just add it as another parameter to the URL connection string: `"jdbc:csv:[DatabasePath]?_CSV_Header=true&_CSV_Quoter='"`

Comment: It worked, thanks! Now, if you have any idea how I can get all numeric values with no decimal places then that would be great! hehe.

Comment: This will work until it doesn't -- i.e. until you encounter data containing the chosen delimiter. I sincerely hope this is not a mission-critical system.

Answer (score 0):

Quotes around fields in a CSV-file have a meaning and are not part of the field content. This is specified by [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-2):

> 5. Each field may or may not be enclosed in double quotes (however some programs, such as Microsoft Excel, do not use double quotes at all). If fields are not enclosed with double quotes, then double quotes may not appear inside the fields. For example:
>    "aaa","bbb","ccc" CRLF
>    zzz,yyy,xxx
>    6. Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas should be enclosed in double-quotes. For example:
>    "aaa","b CRLF
>    bb","ccc" CRLF
>    zzz,yyy,xxx
>    7. If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with another double quote. For example:
>    "aaa","b""bb","ccc"

So, if you want quotes as part of the data the file must look this way:

```
ROW 1. """APPLE""",$1.40
ROW 2. ORANGE,$1.30
ROW 3. """LEMON""",$1.50
```

A possible problem is that not all implementations respect RFC 4180. I hope that Caigen does.